# Can't declare variable in react native npm Time picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I use react native [Time picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) as the date component. when I update time using it, it fails to get and save time in the variable(cdate)

**Props**

```
 constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         cdate: '',
         setDate: '',
         text: '',
         isVisible: false,
         setVisible: false,

      }
```

**In render**

```
 const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;
```

Time picker

```
 <Button title={cdate} onPress={() => this.setState({ setVisible: true })} />
               < DateTimePicker
  mode="time"
  isVisible={setVisible}
  cdate={cdate}
  onConfirm={cdate => {
    this.setState({setDate:cdate.toTimeString(),setVisible:false})
  }}
  onCancel={() => this.setState({ setVisible: false })}
/>
```

I want the button to show the time set in it's title when the time is set

Comment: did you mean that the setDate is not changed?

Comment: yes that's the  issue

Comment: I think maybe the problem is the variable you define is same

Comment: can you share an expo snack with the same code so that we can check?

Comment: @Gaurav Roy I built another app your code runs fine on that must be someting wrong with the current app thank you Gaurav : )

Answer (score 0):

you try to use the following code:

```
handleDatePicked = date => {
    console.log("A date has been picked: ", date);
    this.setState({setDate:date.toTimeString(),setVisible:false})
  };
...
<Button title={cdate} onPress={() => this.setState({ setVisible: true })} />
               < DateTimePicker
  mode="time"
  isVisible={setVisible}
  onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked}
  onCancel={() => this.setState({ setVisible: false })}
/>
```